# Same width for a set of labels using auto layout

Tags: ios, width, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I need to create a simple layout with a few labels and buttons. Here's how I have positioned the UI elements in the IB.

[image]

This is how I want them to look like in the app as well. The label set on the left side with the same width so the elements on the right side will adjust their widths accordingly.

I have set the leading space to superview constraints on the labels on the left side and set vertical spacing between each of them. Similarly I've added trailing space to superview constraint to the labels and buttons on the right side with vertical spacing between each other. I've also added horizontal spacing between each couple of elements (ex: Name <-> John Doe, Telephone <-> button).

When I run it, it looks like this.

[image]

The elements only take up widths as their content needs. I assume this problem occurs because there is no way to auto layout to decide on a width. If I set the labels on the left to same width constraint, it doesn't work at runtime because the constants for them are fixed so they looks like this.

[image]

How can I make them appear properly like I have them in the interface builder?

Thank you.

I uploaded a test Xcode project with this issue [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9jby3dmibez95q/AutoLayoutInARow.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

In your final example, it looks like you almost achieved what you wanted. You made all the labels on the left have the same width. You can now set a width constraint on the first label to a width that works for you, and the other labels should automatically match. The only issue you might still have is getting it to look good on wider screens.

Comment: I just tried that it gives the same result as in the last image I've posted in my question. The left set of labels get the same widths and everything but in the iPhone screen, they push the right set of elements so they get squeezed.